# Brahmamuhurtha and time zone

Tags: brahma, time, muhurta

[Brahmamuhurta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmamuhurtha) is a 48-minute period (muhurta) that begins one hour and 36 minutes before sunrise, and ends 48 minutes before sunrise.

Brahmamuhurtha is considered as auspicious time for all practices of yoga and most appropriate for meditation, worship or any other religious practice

Different places on earth have different time zones or we can say different places have different times of sunrise. So does it mean each different place would be having their own Brahmamuhurta? If this is true then there would always be Brahmamuhurta in some places on the earth. If there is always Brahmamuhurta then does it really have any significance?

Is Brahmamuhurta really auspicious?